# Why does Class.forName not seem to register driver with DriverManager

Tags: java, mysql, jdbc

Being new to JDBC, I was taught to use `Class.forName` to register a driver to `DriverManager`,
which does not seem to work for my code though:

```java
public static void main(String[] args)
{
    System.out.println(DriverManager.drivers().count());

    // clear all loaded drivers
    Iterator<Driver> it = DriverManager.drivers().iterator();

    while (it.hasNext())
    {
        try { DriverManager.deregisterDriver(it.next()); }
        catch (SQLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }
    }

    System.out.println(DriverManager.drivers().count());

    // register mysql driver with forName
    try { Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver"); }
    catch (ClassNotFoundException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

    System.out.println(DriverManager.drivers().count());

    // register with constructor - works fine
    try { DriverManager.registerDriver(new com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver()); }
    catch (SQLException e) { e.printStackTrace(); }

    System.out.println(DriverManager.drivers().count());
}
```

Which always results in 1, 0, 0, 1 whenever I compile and run.
Where have I gone wrong?

Comment: Have you downloaded the correct JDBC drivers ? Also, I would recommend that you fix the indentations to make your code more readable.

Comment: @ParameshSriram What's wrong with my indentation?

Comment: The thing is, I would recommend using a line break after each try or catch statement. For example, use `try { //next line
Insert code //next line }` . This makes the code more readable.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since Java 6 (assuming a JDBC 4.0 or higher driver on the initial classpath), JDBC drivers are loaded automatically. This means that the driver was loaded automatically the moment `DriverManager` was class loaded and initialized.

The static initializer of the driver class is what registers a driver with the driver manager. This static initializer is run when the class is loaded. As the driver class was already loaded, a subsequent `Class.forName` returns the already loaded class, and the static initializer does not run again, so nothing is registered with `DriverManager`.

In other words:

1. `DriverManager` is class loaded and loads drivers using `ServiceLoader`

   - `com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver` is loaded through `ServiceLoader` and its static initializer registers an instance with `DriverManager`
2. You remove all drivers from `DriverManager`
3. You call `Class.forName("com.mysql.cj.jdbc.Driver")`

   - Given the class was already class loaded, Java returns the already loaded class
   - Nothing is registered as the static intializer doesn't run again
4. You manually register an instance with `DriverManager` (BTW, this is not something you should normally do, `DriverManager.registerDriver` is for JDBC drivers to call).

Answer (score 1):

## JDBC drivers automatically registered in modern Java

You said:

> I was taught to use Class.forName

Your teacher is very much out-of-date.

In modern Java, you no longer need to call `Class.forName`. JDBC drivers are now automatically loaded via the Java [*Service Provider Interface (SPI)*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Service_provider_interface). If curious about how this works, see [this Question](https://stackoverflow.com/q/46834483/642706).

If your JDBC driver fails to be automatically registered, verify its inclusion within your project, or if in a Jakarta EE (Java EE) server, verify the proper location within that environment. You have not posted enough details about your development and deployment scenario for us to diagnose. And verify that you have the right version, which generally should support [JDBC 4.x](https://www.jcp.org/en/jsr/detail?id=221) (4.3 is current).

If you continue to have trouble, write a throwaway console app that does *nothing* but connect to your database. Eliminate as much complexity and distraction as possible.

Regarding the code you show, I have no idea why you would want to be de-registering any drivers. Basically, all of the code you showed in your Question should be unnecessary.

## `DataSource`

Furthermore, usually best to use a `DataSource` as the way to get connections to your database. A `DataSource` object holds the information required to connect: server address, port number, username, password, and various proprietary settings specific to your database server product.

I have written a few Answers on Stack Overflow with complete working examples for MySQL, Postgres, & H2. Like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70219064/642706). I suggest you search for such example from me and the many other fine authors on Stack Overflow.

Here is one such example. The code shown here should be sufficient as the MySQL driver should be automatically loaded.

```
private DataSource configureDataSource ( )
{
    System.out.println( "INFO - `configureDataSource` method. " + Instant.now() );

    com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource dataSource = Objects.requireNonNull( new com.mysql.cj.jdbc.MysqlDataSource() );  // Implementation of `DataSource`.
    dataSource.setServerName( "db-mysql-lon2-722-do-user-89973-1.x.db.ondigitalocean.com" );
    dataSource.setPortNumber( 24_090 );
    dataSource.setDatabaseName( "defaultdb" );
    dataSource.setUser( "scott" );
    dataSource.setPassword( "tiger" );
    return dataSource;
}
```

Usage:

```
Connection conn = myDataSource.getConnection() ;
```

Of course you should obtain a `DataSource` implementation that addresses your needs. For example, some provide fresh new connections while others provide connection pooling. Some are provided by the vendor of your database, and some are third-party.